# Companion gear comparison

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When I mouse over gear in SW: TOR, the game shows me the stat comparison between the piece and what I have equipped.

Is there a way to do that for my companion's gear?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because companion stats now come purely from level, Presence, and Influence (as of Patch 4.0).  Companion gear is purely for looks; as such, comparing stats for it is no longer useful.

Comment: @MatthewRead Please check [this meta thread](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11126/should-we-delete-retired-questions) as there's a debate going for closing obsolete questions. As far as I can tell, we should not close them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, go to:

`Preferences - User Interface - Enable Companion Comparative Tooltips`

Note, if your companion has nothing in that slot, nothing shows for them. This can be an issue at the lower levels since it makes it look like it isn't working.

Also, you must have your companion summoned. And it only shows comparisons for the currently summoned companion.